# Who created concepts of force, mass and acceleration, and how did Newton discover that force, mass and acceleration are proportional to each other?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, history

I'm trying to better my understanding of Newton's second law.

Who created the concepts of force, mass and acceleration, and how did Newton discover that force, mass and acceleration are proportional to each other?

Comment: Are you asking for the entire history of how forces were discovered ?

Comment: Lol no, unless you think that would be helpful.

Comment: He saw an apple falling

Comment: Very funny.....

Comment: @watchy http://www.arthurstinner.com/stinner/pdfs/1994-storyofforce.pdf

Comment: Newton and many other scientists did many experiments and observed these relations. But this relation is obvious from day to day life as well. Of course, it is obvious that massive objects don't accelerate much than lighter objects and of course when more force is applied the object accelerate more than when less force is applied. But note that this is not the exact form of Newton's second law, you will need to learn Calculus to understand that, for now, it suffices that you understand this much only.

Comment: Thank you for the link, Mechanic. I'm reading it now... I guess my confusion lies in the discovery of a proportional relationship between two quantites.

Comment: This question is more suitable for [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

> How did Newton discover that force, mass and acceleration are proportional to each other?

Newton introduces his three laws of motion in the very first part of the [*Principia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophi%C3%A6_Naturalis_Principia_Mathematica), titled *Axioms, or Laws of Motion*. In the *Scholium* or discussion section that follows, he describes in some detail the experimental evidence that led him to formulate these laws. At the beginning of the *Scholium* he says

> I have laid down such principles as have been received by mathematicians, and are confirmed by abundance of experiments.

He start5s by describing Galileo's experiments with falling bodies and balls rolling down planes, which led Galileo to propose that falling bodies have a uniform acceleration. Although Newton does not actually use the term *acceleration*, he says the same thing in a more long-winded way:

> When a body is falling, the uniform force of its gravity acting equally, impresses, in equal particles of time, equal forces upon that body, and therefore generates equal velocities; and in the whole time impresses a whole force, and generates a whole velocity proportional to the time.

Newton then describes the "experiment of pendulums" carried out by himself, Christopher Wren and other members of the [Royal Society](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Society). In these experiments an object suspended by a string is released and collides with another suspended object. The velocities of the first object immediately before the collision can be determined from the height at which it is released, and the velocities immediately after collision can be determined from the height which the objects reach after rebounding. These experiments led Newton to formulate the principle of conservation of momentum, which he states as a corollary to his three axioms. Newton concludes his description of the pendulum experiments by saying:

> And thus the third Law, as far as it regards percussion and reflexions, is proved by a theory exactly agreeing with experience.